# Starting an interpreter and dumping the output to a new buffer

Tags: buffers, python

I am working on some Python code, and I would like to call an IPython interpreter from within a script. I have no problem doing this, however, I would then like to dump all of the output from both the script and the interactive session into a new scratch buffer. I know that in general I can use something like

`:new | 0read ! <command>`

to read the output of a shell command into a new buffer. However, if I try opening up a Python interpreter using that format above what ends up happening is that Vim hangs until I do a bunch of C-c and C-z commands, and finally the output of a Python interpreter with a bunch of C-c and C-z command going into it shows up. Is there any way I could run an interactive program like a Python interpreter, interact with that program as I would normally do, and then have that Python session dumped into a new buffer?

Thanks

Comment: If you can't capture such output outside of Vim (i.e. redirecting to a file from shell) then it's not going to happen in Vim. I think you need to approach this from the Python angle: ask something like "Is there a way to capture REPL session in a file?" at an appropriate SE site. Then Vim can handle it just like any other file.

Comment: OTOH, you should be able to run it in a terminal in Vim...depending on what you are trying to do maybe that's good enough.

Comment: @BLayer
I have a script that creates a variable of a type I'm unfamiliar with. I need to extract and process information from it. After the script runs, I have an IPython.embed() statement at the end to start up the interactive interpreter so I can play with the variable the script has created. I would like to pull the IPython session back into a scratch buffer so I can use it as a reference and implement what I need from it in the script. I can just use the %history command to save the session to a file and load it that way, I was wondering if there was a native Vim way to do it I suppose.

Comment: `r !` and `system()`, the standard ways of caputring external program output read stdout. That's a well defined and simple interface. Command line interactive programs, OTOH, are not simple and not standardized. For one thing they may be outputting all kinds of ANSI/terminal codes which are apt to make the stdout listener choke. So unless the interactive program has a mode that makes it behave in a well-defined way you can't predict what will happen when you try to slurp it with Vim. Kinda like what you experienced. Run it in a Vim terminal and yank the text you need is probably your best bet.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Just because it's bugging me I want to clarify... When I say stdout is a simple, well-defined interface I really meant that non-interactive programs behave in simple, well-defined ways (e.g. they don't throw off ANSI/terminal codes willy nilly). Interactive programs don't expect stdout to be captured and therefore don't bother trying to keep their stdout output well-behaved (here come the ANSI codes!)

Comment: @BLayer Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @filbranden

Thank you!